# -bash: fork: can't allocate memory ubuntu 18.04.3

Tags: python, ubuntu

I am running a script on Digital ocean 1GB memory droplet. When I start program memory usage remains under 150MB but suddenly program stops and I get -bash: fork: can't allocate memory error if I run any command. what is causing the issue?
Memory usage when the program is running:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your interactive shell or the script you're running is consuming all the memory it is allowed to get.

You should inspect the output of `uname -a`, and inspect the output of `dmesg`, and inspect the program you're running for a loop or using the `-x` parameter to running it if it is a shell script, as in `bash -x yourprogram`, and seeing if the output looks like never-ending loop to you.

uname will list system resource limits for your user-environment. dmesg will tell you if the system has decided your program is behaving badly and needs some reaping to keep it from dragging everything down. `bash -x` will show all commands as a script executes them.

One of those should lead you to the problem. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you. I will try these and will update here if it solves the problem.

Comment: I worry about that subtle word "remains" in your original post. How long is that going?